How to know when the tcp::acceptor is ready?
I am writing an HTTP server. I have written the following and it works well:
boost::asio::io_context io_context;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, ...);
acceptor.async_accept(...);
auto server_thread = std::jthread([] { io_context.run(); });
// How do I ensure the server is ready? (before calling sendHTTPRequests)
sendHTTPRequests();

I want to start sending HTTP requests immediately. Is there a way to ensure the server is already up and running?

found something that seems to be working:   m_io_context.dispatch([&]{ready = true;});
m_server_thread = std::jthread([this] { m_io_context.run(); });
while (not ready) {};

that works on the assumption there's only one IO thread (which forms an implicit strand)

You can always just wait for things.
Code sketch (untested...):
struct Sync
{
   std::mutex mutex;
   std:condition_variable condition;
   bool ready=false;
};
auto sync=std::make_shared<Sync>();

io_context.post([sync]() {
   {
      std::lock_guard<decltype(sync->mutex)> lock(sync->mutex);
      sync->ready=true;
   }
   sync->condition.notify_all();
});

// Finally, a line from your code :-)
auto server_thread = std::jthread([] { io_context.run(); });

{
   std::unique_lock<decltype(sync->mutex)> lock(sync->mutex);
   sync->condition.wait(lock, [sync]() { return sync->ready; } );
}

sync.reset(); // or just let it drop out of scope


This is a bit heavy weight, and probably also misses the subtler issue. Also, there's a common Asio pattern that uses a timer object for this kind of signalling. It even has cancel() and cancel_one() members for this purpose.

Note that in your question code the first problem is starting the service thread before posting any work.
Otherwise, technically after the acceptor has been opened, connections will already enter the backlog, so you'd be fine.
This makes me guess that starting the thread early (so it runs out of work) was the real problem. Simply putting the async_accept before starting the thread would be enough.

In a simple case like this a 5ms sleep will do. If that somehow really not okay, post your sendHTTPRequests(); operations to the same strand as the async_accept. In your sample, the single service thread forms an implicit strand:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void sendHTTPRequests() {
    tcp::socket c(boost::asio::system_executor{});
    c.connect({{}, 8989});
}

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    tcp::acceptor           acceptor(io_context, {tcp::v4(), 8989});
    acceptor.async_accept([](auto ec, auto s) {
        std::cout << "Connection accepted from " << s.remote_endpoint() << " (" << ec.message() << ")"
                  << std::endl;
    });
    auto server_thread = std::jthread([&] { io_context.run(); });

    post(io_context, sendHTTPRequests);
}

Printing e.g.

Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53714 (Success)

Synchronization
You can also post a packaged_task and await it for old-fashioned thread synchronization without the manual juggling of mutex/condition-variables.
post( //
    io_context,
    asio::use_future([&] { std::cout << "Server ready at " << acceptor.local_endpoint() << std::endl; }))
    .wait();

You can return values:
auto ep = post( //
              io_context, asio::use_future([&] { return acceptor.local_endpoint(); }))
              .get();

std::cout << "Server ready at " << ep << std::endl;
sendHTTPRequests();

See it Live On Coliru
Server ready at 0.0.0.0:8989
Connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57386 (Success)

